# Saving multiple checkbox value and different input value into database as one

Tags: php, laravel, database, web, checkbox

I'm trying to insert a data/value into my database.

It works but the problem is that every time I select the second value/checkbox only its other input value gets the value of the first input.

```
<form action="{{url('/reservation')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="row col-12">
        <div>
            <p class='mybox text-dark'><input type="checkbox" name="prod_name[]" value="JasminBooks"/>JasminBooks</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="prod_qty[]" min="1" value="1"class="form-control ml-2">
        </div>
    <div class="row col-12">
        <div>
            <p class='mybox text-dark'><input type="checkbox" name="prod_name[]" value="KnowHowBooks"/>KnowHowBooks</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="prod_qty[]" min="1" value="1"class="form-control ml-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the code for my controller function

```
public function reservation(Request $request)
{
    $data = new reservation;
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->phone = $request->phone;
    $data->address = $request->address;
    $data->date = $request->date;
    $data->time = $request->time;

    $products = null;
    $checked_array = $_POST['prod_name'];

    foreach($_POST['prod_name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($_POST['prod_name'][$key], $checked_array)) {
            $products .= $_POST['prod_qty'][$key]." ".$_POST['prod_name'][$key].", ";
        }
    }

    $data->products = $products;
    $data->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The result and the data is saved into the database when

1. I select the first checkbox and input a value of quantity 5 the result is "5 JasminBooks,"
2. When I select both checkboxes and input a value of quantity 12 in the first input beside the first checkbox and 7 for the second input/quantity besides the second checkbox the result is "12 JasminBooks, 7 KnowHowBooks, "
3. But when I only select the second checkbox and input a value of 13 for the quantity the result is "1 KnowHowBooks, " it takes the default value of the first input rather than the second input where I inserted 13 as the quantity.

What should I add/change in my code?

Comment: why are you using `$_POST` when Laravel provides a powerful `$request` variable?

Comment: Saving multiple values into a single field as you're doing could be considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). I would recommend reconsidering your implementation (have a look at [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships), particularly the [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship).

Comment: I'm still learning about laravel and I thought I could use $_POST ok like in php. Thanks for telling and giving directions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're defining your quantity fields based on index. If a single input is missing, it could throw off your whole result. Use the value as key:

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <p class='mybox text-dark'><input type="checkbox" name="prod_name[]" value="JasminBooks"/>JasminBooks
    </p></div><div>
    <input type="number" name="prod_qty[JasminBooks]" min="1" value="1"class="form-control ml-2">
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$products = '';
$checked_array = $request->input('prod_name', []);
$quantities = $request->input('prod_qty', []);

foreach ($checked_array as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $quantities)) {
        $products .= "{$quantities[$value]} {$value}, ";
    }
}

// Remove trailing ', '
if (! empty($products)) {
    $products = substr($products, 0, -2);
} 

$data->products = $products;
```

P.S. Like Bhaumik said, don't use `$_POST` in Laravel.

Comment: Thank you @Yinci for providing a solution and I will follow what Bhaumik said. The first if statement lacks ")" so it gives an error but the solution you gave answered my question. tysm

Comment: Oh yes apologies, I'll fix the syntax error